# iPad's UISplitViewController did not rotate well when modalView is rotated

Tags: ipad, rotation, uisplitviewcontroller

I have rotation problem on `UISplitViewController`. In my case, after calling present modal on `splitViewController` (this splitViewController is the root view of window) to show another view. When that modalView is rotated, the splitView rotate incorrectly.

The splitView appears like it rotated, but the `DetailViewController` stays like it appear on portrait, and the `RootViewController` did not show at all. It still behave like on portrait mode. It seems that the splitView is rotated, but not the underlying views (`DetailViewController` and `RootViewController`).

I try to implement `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` on the modalView, and call the splitView's `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method using delegate.

This is what I implement in modalView:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    MacProjectAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate.splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}
```

The result is, the `DetailViewController` behave correctly, but not with `RootViewController`. It stay hidden. It will re-appear after the user manually rotate to portrait and back to landscape. But obviously user did not want that.

This is what I did when presenting modalView:

```
ModalViewController *modalView = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
MacProjectAppDelegate *delegate = (MacProjectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.splitViewController presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];
[modalView release];
```

Is there a way to show the `RootViewController` in this case? Or is my doing things is wrong?

Edit:
It seems all views did not rotate following the modalView. neither the RootViewController nor DetailViewController did rotate (`the didRotateFromOrientation` on both ViewController did not called at all). So now I assume it didn't rotate following the device/modalView.

Comment: Have you tried to present your modalViewController from `DetailViewController` and not from UISplitView directly?

Comment: I've tried it and it's not working. The solution I've workout so far is acquiring `appDelegate` and get the `splitViewController` to call `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` twice. One at `modalView`'s `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method, one at `RootViewController`'s `willAppear` method.

But this approach still have a problem. `The DetailViewController` still show the navigator button like when it's on portrait mode. I still working on this one.

Comment: I'm having same problem. Look at my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767302/how-to-inform-the-parent-viewcontroller-about-the-changed-screen-orientation-in/10623628#10623628

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. My problem has been solved.
What I did is as I wrote as comment on Shurakov's comment.

I acquire appDelegate and get the splitViewController to call willRotateToInterfaceOrientation.

```
MacProjectAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
```

I did it twice since only one of them seems did not work (I don't know why). One at `modalViewController`'s `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method, one at `RootViewController`'s `willAppear` method.

To remove the navigator/popover button on `DetailViewController`, I simply invalidate that button by calling `invalidateRootPopoverButtonItem` at `RootViewController`'s `willAppear` method. This is what it's looks like on this particular method (for the first one at `modalViewController`, I just pass the `willRotateToOrientation` command to `splitViewController`):

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
    MacProjectAppDelegate *delegate = (MacProjectAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate.splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:orientation duration:1];
    [[[delegate.splitViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] invalidateRootPopoverButtonItem:self.rootPopoverButtonItem];        
}
```

Hope this can explain how I overcome my problem and help anyone who had the same problem as me.