# UIWebView: Fit frame to view size, allow scrollowing within that frame on UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiwebview, uiscrollview

This problem is driving me nuts.

I have a UIWebView which I am trying to make fill the full view on the right side of a UISplitViewController:

```
CGSize boundsSize = self.view.bounds.size;
self.webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, boundsSize.width, boundsSize.height)] autorelease];
self.webView.delegate = self;
self.webView.opaque = NO;
self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
self.webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAddress | UIDataDetectorTypeLink | UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

First of all, how do I account for making the frame size fit the view when I don't know the orientation?  Can I autoresize to the appropriate size?

Next, when I load my HTML into my webView I want the frame size to stay the same (just like a UIScrollView does), but have that new content be able to be scrolled with that frame.  Some content is much longer, some is not.  So, I have tried to adjust the frame, but this just makes my frame larger rather than my content size.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {

    // Calculate the size of our webview
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    aWebView.frame = frame;

}//end
```

Is this not possible?  Do I need to put the webView inside of a UIScrollView and set the contentSize of that to the height of my new content every time I load it into my webView?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Seems I had to manually adjust my frame on load:

```
    // Orientation
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    // Create frame
    CGRect frame;
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 748, 1024);
    } else {
        frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1022);
    }//end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that is all you need to make this work.

**[articleWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];**

Answer (score 0):

Gave a look at the autoresize mask. I think that is all you need to make this work.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6

Comment: Sorry, I do have that already, just forgot to post it here. Added to my example.

Comment: You might be running into this problem in iOS 5.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767302/how-to-inform-the-parent-viewcontroller-about-the-changed-screen-orientation-in